# Why command create-react-app doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create react project, but something is wrong. I don't understand how to fix it.

[image: SCREENSHOT FROM CMD]

Comment: where is your screen?

Comment: Don't know why screenshot didn't add. Hier is screenshot:
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/864905227903303722/921108746904666122/unknown.png

Answer (score 0):

Check the versions of npm and node if it is ( Node >= 10.0.0 and npm >= 5.2 ) and try again. (npx create-react-app  )

Answer (score 0):

They recently released a new version of `create-react-app`, and therefore may require you to reset your cache by either running:

```
npx clear-npx-cache
```

or by ensuring you are running the latest version of `create-react-app` using:

```
npx create-react-app@latest <project name>
```